# How do I make a python daemon run at bootup?

Tags: python, daemon, rc

I am writing a Python program that will act as a custom converter for a hardware application for me on the raspberry pi.

I have written python code to act as a daemon, but how do I go about making it run at bootup.

I know about using cron, but I plan on packaging this and it would make sense if it started along with the other daemons (syslogd, sshd, etc) at the correct run level.

Comment: What OS do you have running on your RPi? That would determine how to set it up as a start-up service.

Comment: Rasbian, its a Debian based one.

Answer (score 0):

Have your init system start it when the computer boots up.

If you are using SysVinit, all you would need to do is place a shell script that would execute your program into /etc/rc.d/init.d/.